# Storing multiple types in same object

Tags: c#, types

First I will give a little background info so this question isn't completely without context:

I am writing a program which needs to read in binary files of which I know the format/layout. The bulk of these files contain "structs", with the layout of each stored in the header of the file. Each struct contains fields which could be either structs or "base" types (which are not structs, and can be either value or reference types like `float` or `String` or `Vector3`).

I do not need to access most of the data in these files, so I would not have to define all possible structs for my current project, but there are enough that I would have to define that doing it manually would be tedious and time consuming.

My problem is that there are an extremely large number of these structs (2500+ different ones, though only the ones appearing in a file are defined in that file's header). I would like to be able to read them in, without having to manually define each one, in a way that makes all the data available in the same way. My current thinking is that I should create a class like this:

```
class Struct{
  StructDefinition _def;
  List < Field > _fields;
  ...
}
```

In the field class I would need to be able to store both structs AND base types (or more importantly reference and value types). Is there a way to do this without turning everything into an `object` then casting it to the correct type when I need it? Also, is this the best way to go about reading in these files, or is there a better method?

Comment: Reading in the files is only the start of the problem. You have to process them next. Pretend you've read them in to the structure you defined - now write the code to process that struct - see if it's easy or hard, obvious, or confusing. You may change your mind about what data structure to use.

Comment: You bring up an good point. I had not thought about how it would be used very much. I think I have to sacrifice some usability if I don't want to define things manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dynamic` (.NET 4.0) can do this at runtime, but you lose compile-time type safety and IntelliSense.

For your particular situation, I would recommend the new file mapping classes in .NET 4.0.

If you need a pre-.NET 4.0 solution, consider looking at the file as a series of offsets instead of structures, and use a `FileStream`, seeking to and reading in only the information you need. This is kind of like a poor-man's file mapping. Note that in this situation, it's more performant if you only move forward through the file.

Using either of these last two solutions, you don't have to waste time and memory reading in data you won't need anyway.

Comment: This (filestream) would have been my first choice, however some of these structs contain references and lists. While it would still be possible using offsets, it gets confusing VERY quickly and makes it difficult to debug.

Comment: I know what you mean. One approach that has helped me is to re-write the file layout specification (at least the parts I need) using just file offsets. e.g., if structure A contains structure B after a couple of `int`s, then rewrite it so that `offset(B) = offset(A) + 8`. After the file spec has been rewritten, then attempt coding.

Answer (score 0):

If you define an interface that contains all of the methods that you need to manipulate the fields, then you can create a small set of objects - one for reference and one for value types. 
As long as each of these objects implement the same interface, you will be able to work with them generically.